# C#: What's the "=> . <=" Operator?

Tags: c#, syntax, shorthand

In C#, What does the "=> x <=" operator mean?
Where the arrows point towards the variable x in the middle.

The code where I found it in:

```
public static bool Check(this int x) => x <= 2;
```

Comment: It's not one operator.  `=>` is for expression-bodied members (in this case) and lambdas.  `<=` is just "less than or equal". It can be rewritten as `=> (x <= 2)` without changing the meaning. You can learn about them separately to understand what's happening there.

Answer (score 4):

This is two separate operators that look similar, but are quite different. The first part indicates an *expression-bodied member* (`=>`), which in this case is being used as shorthand to declare the method implementation. It's equivalent to this:

```
public static bool Check(this int x)
{
    return x <= 2;
}
```